# Calculate integral similar to modified Bessel function: $\int_1^\infty \frac{\textrm{e}^{-\textrm{i} k x}}{\sqrt{(x-\textrm{i} y)^2 -1}} \textrm{d} x$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am looking for help calculating

$$ I(k,y) = \int_1^\infty \frac{\textrm{e}^{-\textrm{i} k x}}{\sqrt{(x-\textrm{i} y)^2 -1}} \textrm{d} x, $$

where we assume that $k$ has small, negative imaginary part and $y$ is real and positive.

There is an expression in the case $y=0$ from the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32): [(picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2jix.png) but I can't relate this to $I(k,y)$ without introducing an extra integral to calculate.

I've tried contour integration, expanding the square root function as a Taylor series, and comparing with other Bessel, Hankel and Struve identities, but nothing seems to work.